# How to search the items in multiple arrays efficiently?

Tags: java, algorithm

Currently I have 5 sorted arrays and they all are size of 3. In future, it can be 10000 sorted arrays and 100000 number of elements in it. And I am trying to search for single element in each of the 5 arrays (or its predecessor, if it doesn't exist).

Obviously, I can binary search each array individually, which will result in O(k log n) where k is number of sorted arrays.

Can we do it in O(log n)? As I think there might be some better way of doing it as we're doing the same searches k times

Below is my code which will take O(k log n) -

```
public class SearchItem {

    private List<List<Integer>> dataInput;

    public SearchItem(final List<List<Integer>> inputs) {
        dataInput = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for (List<Integer> input : inputs) {
            dataInput.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(input));
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getItem(final Integer x) {
        List<Integer> outputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (List<Integer> data : dataInput) {
            int i = Collections.binarySearch(data, x); // binary searching the item
            if (i < 0)
                i = -(i + 1);
            outputs.add(i == data.size() ? null : data.get(i));
        }
        return outputs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6));
        List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 8, 13));

        lists.add(list1);
        lists.add(list2);
        lists.add(list3);
        lists.add(list4);
        lists.add(list5);

        SearchItem search = new SearchItem(lists);

        List<Integer> dataOuput = search.getItem(3);

        System.out.println(dataOuput);
    }

}
```

Any idea how this can be achieved in O(log n)? I would like to keep the `SearchItem` constructor input parameter as it is which will accept List of List..

There might be some efficient way to do this.. may be we need to merge the arrays together?

Comment: You mean `O(log(nk))` I assume?

Comment: I guess no, as we need to perform separate binary search in each of k lists. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: This is pointless: you have 15 elements; even a linear search of each array will be ridiculously fast. You'd be better off spending your time elsewhere.

Comment: That's just an example on few elements.. I can have 1000 of sorted arrays with 10000 elements in it.

Comment: Ah, well then you should probably specify that! In that case, the problem become dependent on how often your sorted lists are changing. If they're relatively static, then the up-front cost of simple k-way merge is probably worth it. If they are being updated frequently, then the frequent merging will likely outweigh the jump from klog(n) to log(kn). Anyway, without knowing a lot more, this is pretty unanswerable.

Comment: Sure.. I just updated my question with that.. Any of those sorted arrays won't be getting updated, it will be static once gets generated.. So you think merging them together will be efficient?

Comment: Please note that this question has also been asked here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/how-to-optimize-the-code-while-searching-the-items-in-multiple-arrays .

Comment: @Josay: Yeah.. somehow I thought that it is good suited for codereview.. But then I posted it here.. I am going to delete that one.. Just deleted now to avoid duplicacy..

Comment: Fine for me, I just wanted to pointed out so that no one bothers writing an already given answer.

Comment: Sure.. I will make a not of that.. Thanks.

Comment: @dlev: Can you help me on this? I have also updated the question with the details of number of sorted arrays and elements thing..

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks for the suggestion.. That's what I was thinking as well.. Can you provide a simple example which can help me to understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working class that transfers the work load from the searching to the data loading.

public class TestSearch {

```
public TestSearch(List<List<Integer>> dataInput) {
    this.dataInput = dataInput;
    int searchResultIndex = 0;
    minSearchItem = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    maxSearchItem = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (List<Integer> list : dataInput) {
        for (Integer item : list) {
            if (item > maxSearchItem ) {
                maxSearchItem = item;
            }
            if (item < minSearchItem) {
                minSearchItem = item;
            }
            List searchResultsList = searchResults.get(item);
            if (searchResultsList == null)  {
                searchResultsList = Arrays.asList(null,null,null,null,null);
                searchResults.put(item,searchResultsList);
            }
            if (minimums.get(searchResultIndex) == null) {
                minimums.set(searchResultIndex, item);
            }
            for (int key : searchResults.keySet())  {
                if (key < item && searchResults.get(key).get(searchResultIndex) == null) {
                    searchResults.get(key).set(searchResultIndex,item);
                }
            }
            searchResultsList.set(searchResultIndex,item);
        }
        searchResultIndex++;
    }
}

private List<List<Integer>> dataInput;
private List<Integer> minimums =Arrays.asList(null,null,null,null,null);
private Integer minSearchItem;
private Integer maxSearchItem;
private Map<Integer,List<Integer>> searchResults = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>(15);


public List<Integer> getItem(final Integer x) {
    if (x <= minSearchItem) {
        return minimums;
    }
    if (x > maxSearchItem) {
        return Arrays.asList(null,null,null,null,null);
    }
    List<Integer>outputs =  searchResults.get(x);
    int nextKey = x + 1;
    while (outputs ==  null) {
        outputs = searchResults.get(nextKey);
        nextKey++;
    }
    return outputs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 6));
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 8, 13));

    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list3);
    lists.add(list4);
    lists.add(list5);

    TestSearch search = new TestSearch(lists);

    List<Integer> dataOuput = search.getItem(0);

    System.out.println(dataOuput);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. One quick question.. What will be time complexity for the getItem method in this case.. Any thoughts?

Comment: the getItem method is very fast.  It is a couple of compares and hashmap lookup.

Comment: A quick perusal of that article seems very close to my solution.

Comment: I see and also, you have `Arrays.asList(null,null,null,null,null);` in which you have null 5 times which means it depends on number of sorted arrays I have? In general this parameter will be configurable in my code so depending on that parameter I will generate number of sorted lists..

Comment: It is not hard to fill an arbitrarily size list with nulls.  List<Integer> emptyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(j);  for (i=0;i<j;i++) { emptyList.add(null); }

Comment: yeah I was able to fix that.. In general do you know what will be the complexity for the getItem method? Just trying to understand what it will be? Does it look like O(k + log n) where k is number of sorted arrays?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48699/discussion-between-ssh-and-user3360944)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it faster than O(n log n) but that will require for you to merge the arrays (add them all together) into a TreeSet (or a TreeMap with dummy values). The add operation will have complexity O(n). Then extracting the element will have complexity O(1) - this is only if you use a TreeSet or TreeMap or similar data structure. Hence total time complexity in this case will be O(n) - faster than O(n log n) but slower than O(log n). I cannot think of doing a binary search over the whole group of arrays at one go without somehow merging them.

The rough algorithm would be:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for i = 0 to 4 // number_of_arrays = 5 in your case
   for j = 0 to 2 // for Array of length 3 as you mentioned
   // Depending on how you have your arrays this will change
      set.add(a[i][j]); // 2 dimensional arrays are an array of arrays
boolean flag = set.contains(element); // true if element present
if (flag == true)
   // do logic for element present
else
   // do logic for element not present
```

Comment: If I am going to use TreeMap, then what will be my key for that map?

Comment: The key for your map would be your entry (of type Integer in your case) and the value could be anything (a dummy placeholder, say null) should do it. You could also use a HashSet - does not require values and just your entries would do it. Keep in mind that in the case of a set, duplicates would be eliminated and if you need to preserve them, then go with TreeMap.

Comment: I don't need to preserve them.. I can directly use TreeSet.. Can you provide an example if possible?

Comment: Explained the rough algorithm in the answer as it was easier to format

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will make it faster, but as you are searching for multiple occurrences, maybe you could keep a TreeMap as index, where you'd have the elements as keys and the index of the arrays where they are as the values: `map.get(3);` will return a list with 0,1,2,3,4 and `map.get(13);` will return 5. If the number of occurrences of an element in different lists is low this will save you a lot of binary searches (case of 13).